# How does remote control in raspbmc work

Tags: raspbmc

I am very interested how it is possible that my raspbmc is accepting signals from the remote of my Sony TV. I hope you don't misunderstand me.
Everything works fine!
But i want to know with which technique it's possible to control raspbmc via remote because it's connected to the TV only by an HDMI-cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control#CEC). It runs over pin13 of the HDMI connector

> Consumer Electronics Control (CEC) is an HDMI feature designed to
>   allow the user to command and control up-to 15 CEC-enabled devices,
>   that are connected through HDMI

It can work in both directions. raspbmc can also turn the TV on and make itself the active source